# Connecting Power BI to Postgres Database - What value goes into "Server" field?

Tags: postgresql, powerbi

I'm pretty frustrated - Power BI requires me to enter a value in the field "server" in order to connect to a postgres db on my machine, but I cannot determine any way to retrieve that value from Postgres.  Everything I get by googling seems to involve hostname/localhost, etc., not the server name.  It seems mind-boggling to me that, if I have a server on which my database is running, Postgres won't provide me with any easy way to retrieve its name (and it must have one).  Getting Power BI to connect to Postgres seems way, way too complicated.

Comment: You can refer to the local machine by either its hostname or by `localhost`.

Comment: Three is more than one way to connect.  If you can't describe the UI you are using more precisely, you should at least show an image of it.  If it asks for server but not also for a host, then 'server' most likely means 'host', and as your googling showed, you could use "localhost".  What happened when you tried it?